# Merging two databases in R

Tags: r, matching

I have two survey datasets which I want to combine for my study. The sample data look like this:

```
**Data A**
X      Y         Z  Participation (in %)
24    Black     10000      10
28    Hispanic  250000     12
54    White     20000      32
32    White     32000      14

**`Data B`**
    X       Y        Z   Crime (in %)
    24    Black     10000      4
    28    Hispanic  250000     3
    32    White     320000     5
```

Data A and B have X, Y, Z variables in common. The unique variable for data A is participation and that for data B is crime. Here is what I wanted to do:

a. Partition each dataset into 9 cells as follows:

```
             Age group
   Race    24-40  41-50  51-60 
   White
  Hispanic
   Black
```

b. Rank each cell on the basis of variable Z.

c. Include 10 observations of A for each observation of B.

d. Draw a random sample of A so that number of observations of A is equal to B.

e. Match the rank samples A and B one to one.

I know that R has special package called StatsMatch for this. It, however, doesn't meet my requirements. As far as I understand, it does **a** and **e** and skips the middle steps. I am novice regarding this package and want to learn from an experienced user of this community.

Comment: It'd help if you show the output at each stage for this dataset.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you exactly want in each of the steps. Especially steps c and d are unclear to me. It would also help if you would have some code that generates an example dataset.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the sqldf package to answer questions a-c. Unfortunately I cannot do this without a unique identifier for each person/row shared by both datasets. For example, using column X would work if each person/row did not share the same age. If you had two people/rows aged 24 then this column cannot serve as a unique identifier.

Please provide more information about your data then we can think of a way to create a unique identifier.

Comment: @user1493368, what happens if "some explanatory variables like X and Y" are not unique characteristics for each person/row? Also, will a merge command simply answer questions b & c if the characteristics are not unique?

Could you provide some code for your simple solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Proposed answer

Since no data was provided (but was hinted) I'll generate dataframes `A` and `B` based on those hints (*i.e.* X->Age(Int); Y->Race(Factor); Z->?(Int), maybe population?). Also, I asume you have dataframes A and B already loaded in the R session workspace. Then I asume that the items are not sequential, but you actually want to perform (*a*, *b*, *e*) over samples generated by (*c*, *d*); that is:

- **Step 1** Include 10 observations of A for each observation of B, save as dataframe `moreA`.
- **Setp 2** Draw a random sample of A so that number of observations of A is equal to B, save as `equalA`.
- Partition each of `moreA`, `equalA` and `B` into 9 cells of `race x age_group`, with each cell representing the sum of `Z` and `age group` having range (24, 60) and cut in (41, 51). Save as `moreAtable`, `equalAtable` and `Btable`, respectively. Each cell also "knows" the average of `Crime` or `Participation`.
- Rank each cell in `moreAtable`, `equalAtable` and `Btable` acording to the sum of `Z` which it represents.
- Match each of `moreAtable` and `equalAtable` with `Btable`, based on the rank, and save to  `moreAB` and `equalAB`, respectively.

> For all this I will assume that `nrow(A) >> nrow(B)`, at least enough to get 10 rows of `A` for each row of `B`.

Generate the datasets

Age(24,61) and race(Black,Hispanic, White) are sampled uniformly from their spaces. Percentages are sampled from toy beta distributions and represented as a number in [0, 100]. Ages are then cut into the requested ranges.

```
# Reproducible sampling
set.seed(2013^2 * 3)

# Dataset B:
nrB <- 1000  # number of rows in B
B <- data.frame(X = sample(x = 24:60, size = nrB, replace = TRUE), Y = sample(x = c("Black", 
    "Hispanic", "White"), size = nrB, replace = TRUE), Z = sample(x = (1:300) * 
    1000, size = nrB, replace = TRUE), Crime = round(rbeta(n = nrB, shape1 = 0.5, 
    shape2 = 0.5) * 100, 2))

# Dataset B
nrA <- nrB * 20  # times of rows B = rows in A
A <- data.frame(X = sample(x = 24:60, size = nrA, replace = TRUE), Y = sample(x = c("Black", 
    "Hispanic", "White"), size = nrA, replace = TRUE), Z = sample(x = (1:300) * 
    1000, size = nrA, replace = TRUE), Participation = round(rbeta(n = nrB, 
    shape1 = 0.8, shape2 = 2) * 100, 2))

# Now lets cut the ages
B$AgeGroup <- cut(B$X, breaks = c(24, 41, 51, 60), labels = c("24-40", "41-50", 
    "51-60"), right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)

A$AgeGroup <- cut(A$X, breaks = c(24, 41, 51, 60), labels = c("24-40", "41-50", 
    "51-60"), right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)

# Show data
head(A)
##    X        Y      Z Participation AgeGroup
## 1 53    Black 167000         20.39    51-60
## 2 36    White 130000          3.10    24-40
## 3 57    White 101000         32.41    51-60
## 4 60    Black  28000         72.29    51-60
## 5 58    Black 172000         22.10    51-60
## 6 59 Hispanic  51000         69.01    51-60

head(B)
##    X        Y      Z Crime AgeGroup
## 1 58    White 118000  8.10    51-60
## 2 33    Black  97000 36.58    24-40
## 3 44 Hispanic 212000  3.62    41-50
## 4 29 Hispanic 108000 35.13    24-40
## 5 53    Black 175000 96.47    51-60
## 6 58    Black 291000  4.41    51-60
```

Generate both A sample datasets

Lets get the sample A datasets. For the longer one, we sample 10 for each on in B. For the equal length on, we sample A:B.

```
# Longer A
moreA <- A[sample(x = 1:nrow(A), size = 10 * nrow(B)), ]

# Equal A
equalA <- A[sample(x = 1:nrow(A), size = nrow(B)), ]
```

Partition the datasets into 3x3 matrices

Actually I won't partition into 3x3 matrices, since it would be much easier to work with a dataframe. For this I'll use the package `plyr`, so be sure you have it installed (or are able to do so).

```
# Try to load plyr. If not installed, try to install and then load it
if (!require("plyr")) {
    install.packages("plyr")
    library("plyr")
}

## Loading required package: plyr

# For each YxAgeGroup, sum Z and average the unique variable

Btable <- ddply(.data = B, .variables = c("Y", "AgeGroup"), .fun = function(x) {
    c(totalZ = sum(x$Z, na.rm = TRUE), meanCrime = mean(x$Crime, na.rm = TRUE))
})

moreAtable <- ddply(.data = moreA, .variables = c("Y", "AgeGroup"), .fun = function(x) {
    c(totalZ = sum(x$Z, na.rm = TRUE), meanParticipation = mean(x$Participation, 
        na.rm = TRUE))
})

equalAtable <- ddply(.data = equalA, .variables = c("Y", "AgeGroup"), .fun = function(x) {
    c(totalZ = sum(x$Z, na.rm = TRUE), meanParticipation = mean(x$Participation, 
        na.rm = TRUE))
})
```

Rank the tables

Now rank each table according to the total Z

```
Btable$rank <- rank(x = Btable$totalZ)
moreAtable$rank <- rank(x = moreAtable$totalZ)
equalAtable$rank <- rank(x = equalAtable$totalZ)
```

Merge each of the A tables with B

An lastly merge each of A tables with B

```
moreAB <- merge(Btable, moreAtable, by = "rank", suffixes = c("_B", "_A"))

equalAB <- merge(Btable, equalAtable, by = "rank", suffixes = c("_B", "_A"))

moreAB
##   rank      Y_B AgeGroup_B totalZ_B meanCrime      Y_A AgeGroup_A
## 1    1    White      51-60 12342000     53.41    Black      51-60
## 2    2    Black      41-50 13197000     51.11    White      51-60
## 3    3 Hispanic      41-50 13198000     50.44 Hispanic      41-50
## 4    4 Hispanic      51-60 13440000     50.70 Hispanic      51-60
## 5    5    White      41-50 14290000     51.70    White      41-50
## 6    6    Black      51-60 14526000     43.11    Black      41-50
## 7    7    White      24-40 21290000     50.46 Hispanic      24-40
## 8    8    Black      24-40 21607000     47.48    Black      24-40
## 9    9 Hispanic      24-40 23743000     50.17    White      24-40
##    totalZ_A meanParticipation
## 1 132935000             27.46
## 2 133766000             28.07
## 3 134911000             27.40
## 4 136962000             26.97
## 5 137234000             27.14
## 6 137315000             27.03
## 7 227174000             28.38
## 8 237046000             27.95
## 9 243853000             28.00

equalAB
##   rank      Y_B AgeGroup_B totalZ_B meanCrime      Y_A AgeGroup_A totalZ_A
## 1    1    White      51-60 12342000     53.41 Hispanic      41-50 10528000
## 2    2    Black      41-50 13197000     51.11    White      41-50 12770000
## 3    3 Hispanic      41-50 13198000     50.44    Black      51-60 13144000
## 4    4 Hispanic      51-60 13440000     50.70    White      51-60 14139000
## 5    5    White      41-50 14290000     51.70    Black      41-50 15029000
## 6    6    Black      51-60 14526000     43.11 Hispanic      51-60 16524000
## 7    7    White      24-40 21290000     50.46 Hispanic      24-40 19075000
## 8    8    Black      24-40 21607000     47.48    Black      24-40 21793000
## 9    9 Hispanic      24-40 23743000     50.17    White      24-40 25538000
##   meanParticipation
## 1             24.34
## 2             29.66
## 3             30.40
## 4             28.30
## 5             29.65
## 6             24.30
## 7             29.17
## 8             30.62
## 9             30.82
```

Does that work?